Im trying to extract data based on object values in javascript
{
      "id": 6,
      "createdAt": "2024-07-24T11:33:05.749Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-07-24T11:33:05.749Z",
      "deletedAt": null,
      "name": "vendor_cashier",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "id": 18,
          "createdAt": "2024-07-24T11:33:05.683Z",
          "updatedAt": "2024-07-24T11:33:05.683Z",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "code": "can_read_pos_device"
        },
        {
          "id": 19,
          "createdAt": "2024-07-24T11:33:05.683Z",
          "updatedAt": "2024-07-24T11:33:05.683Z",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "code": "can_update_pos_device"
        }
      ]
    }

And I need the following sample:
{
   "name":"vendor_cashier",
   "page":"pos-device",
   "permissions":"(list)|(edit)|(show)"
}

I have been trying for hourst but can't think of a solution, can someone help, and Thanks in advance

I would suggest you start by reading up on Working with Objects.

Where do the page and permissions values in your "following sample" come from? I see no similar values in your example data.

Page and permissions comes from permissions array in the main object,
Its called "can_read_pos_device", so I replaced "can_read_pos_device" with "pos-device", and for the permissions I replace "can_read_pos_device" with "(list)|(show)" and "can_update_pos_device" with "(edit)", so it becomes like this "(list)|(edit)|(show)"

What's your sticking point? Where are you stuck? Perhaps show how you are replacing your values in your end result.

Please add the code that you used when you tried it.

In functional way, it may be seen as a data reducing case.
The list of objects in permissions array is to be reduced to only one object as below.
{
   "name":"vendor_cashier",
   "page":"pos-device",
   "permissions":"(list)|(edit)|(show)"
}

Please see below a sample code using the reducer function. At the bottom of the listing of codes, the test results also have been enclosed.
Coding highlights
a. The array permissions has been reduced to a single object. It is implemented by the reducer function in array object.
b. And the resultant object has been been merged with the property name which is not available in the permission array. This has been done with Object.assign function.
code.js
/*

For testing, there are four cases provided below.
By turning on the appropriate switch cases, the respective use cases can be tested.
For eg. useCase = 1, useCase = 2

*/

let obj = null;
const useCase = 1;

switch (useCase) {
  case 1: // update, read and update - three entries in the array
    obj = {
      name: 'vendor_cashier',
      permissions: [
        {
          code: 'can_update_pos_device',
        },
        {
          code: 'can_read_pos_device',
        },
        {
          code: 'can_update_pos_device',
        },
      ],
    };
    break;
  case 2: // read, update and read - three entries in the array.
    obj = {
      name: 'vendor_cashier',
      permissions: [
        {
          code: 'can_read_pos_device',
        },
        {
          code: 'can_update_pos_device',
        },
        {
          code: 'can_read_pos_device',
        },
      ],
    };
    break;
  case 3: // update, update - two entries in the array
    obj = {
      name: 'vendor_cashier',
      permissions: [
        {
          code: 'can_update_pos_device',
        },
        {
          code: 'can_update_pos_device',
        },
      ],
    };
    break;
  case 4: // read and read - two entries in the array
    obj = {
      name: 'vendor_cashier',
      permissions: [
        {
          code: 'can_read_pos_device',
        },
        {
          code: 'can_read_pos_device',
        },
      ],
    };
}

const newObj = Object.assign(
  { name: obj.name },
  obj.permissions.reduce((a, b) => {
    console.log(a.permissions);
    const tempObj = {};

    /*
       All objects containing the string 'can_read_pos_device' has
       has been reduced to the string 'pos-device'. Occurrence in the end
       of a string other than the specified string will result a null 
       value. While seeing the test cases this will become more clear.
       Case 1 and Case 3 will result null values as per this implementation.
    */
    tempObj['code'] =
      a.code == 'can_read_pos_device' || b.code == 'can_read_pos_device'
        ? 'pos-device'
        : null;
    /*
    Conditional 1 : It checks for all contineous occurrences of the string 'can_read_pos_device'
    Conditional 2 : It checks for all contineous occurrences of the string 'can_update_pos_device'
    Conditional 3 : The else part works for mixed cases. It means there are objects with both strings.
    Note : 
    There is an assumption taken here that, any occurrences of the strings other than the two mentioned above,
    will be interpreted as '(list)|(show)|(edit)'. For example, a string 'can_readX_pos_device' will be interpreted
    as '(list)|(show)|(edit)'.

    Since the code is inside a reducer function, a.code and a.permissions would require some discussion to understand.
    a.code will have significance only for the first invocation of the reducer function. For all subsequent calls, a.permissions
    will be valid and will act in place of a.code.
    */
    if (
      (a.code == 'can_read_pos_device' || a.permissions == '(list)|(show)') &&
      b.code == 'can_read_pos_device'
    ) {
      tempObj['permissions'] = '(list)|(show)';
    } else if (
      (a.code == 'can_update_pos_device' || a.permissions == '(edit)') &&
      b.code == 'can_update_pos_device'
    ) {
      tempObj['permissions'] = '(edit)';
    } else {
      tempObj['permissions'] = '(list)|(show)|(edit)';
    }

    return tempObj;
  })
);
console.log(`case :  ${useCase}`);
console.log(newObj);

Test results:
Case 1:
case :  1
{
  name: 'vendor_cashier',
  code: null,
  permissions: '(list)|(show)|(edit)'
}

Case 2:
case :  2
{
  name: 'vendor_cashier',
  code: 'pos-device',
  permissions: '(list)|(show)|(edit)'
}

Case 3:
case :  3
{ name: 'vendor_cashier', code: null, permissions: '(edit)' }

Case 4:
case :  4
{
  name: 'vendor_cashier',
  code: 'pos-device',
  permissions: '(list)|(show)'
}

